# How to change the value of a variable once per day in ios

Tags: ios, nsdate, nscalendar

I am newbie in iOS development so sorry for this question but i want to know that how to change my variable value every day 
like as

today my variable value is like as first time `int a=1` and i wan't to change it tomorrow like as `int a=2` and so on how it possible.

Thank You.

Comment: What is the purpose ? Why you need to increment that day by day ?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the actual thing that you want to achieve in your app? I very much doubt that incrementing a variable once per day is the best solution. There will be many different ways to do what you want but without knowing what that is it's impossible to help.

Comment: already i want to restore value of my variable every day here i post only example. like as today my variable value is YES then i want to change it tomorrow as NO.

Comment: @NoneOfAbove Yes... But **why** do you think you need to do that? There must be a reason for changing that variable? What is it? You are asking about how to make your solution work. Ask about what your problem is in first place.